# Access method on component VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a method in parent that add an element to an array and I am not sure how to use it in my component (add-new-element). Basically in that method I add a new element to array to reload the data from table.

**Parent**

```
   <add-new-element id="add-element" @isAdded="onAddElement" ></add-new-customer>

   onAddElement(newElement){
       console.log('Reload table');
       this.items.unshift(newElement);
   },
```

**Child**

```
data() {
    return{
        isAdded: false,
    };
},
```

Comment: You need to emit the event from your child, and then listen for that event in the parent template. However, if your parent is responsible for adding new elements, why would you need to do the round trip? Whatever handler you are calling in the parent that adds the new element should invoke the additional logic that you want. Can you create a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example?

Comment: In my child I send data to server, and I write the template, and in parent I unshift the element to array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to have a component re-render when data changes, this is automatic already if set in your data.

To have a child component access a method of a parent, use `$emit` and listen for it on the parent.

PARENT:

```
<ChildComponent v-on:added="onAddElement"/>
```

CHILD:

```
method: {
     elementAdded () {
          this.$emit('added', myArgument)
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but It doesn't access the methods (elementAdded ,onAddElement )

Comment: Make sure the first argument is a string. Documentation here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html